Fill in matrix entries to minimize the rank
Let's say you have a matrix $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, for example, this $4 \times 4$ matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d \\\ e & f & g & h \\\ i & j & k & l \\\ m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix}$$
Some of the entries are given to you as real values, but some are left "blank" for you to fill in for yourself, like this:
$$\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & * & 0.5 & * \\\ 0 & * & * & 6 \\\ 4.3 & 5 & * & 8 \\\ * & * & -4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$
How would you fill in these "blank" entries to minimize the rank of matrix $\tilde{A}$?
More generally, what would be the general strategy to do this for any arbitrary $m \times n$ matrix with any arbitrary "blank" masks?
If a general solution is too difficult to find, one thing I am curious about is how the difficulty of this problem behaves as the number of blanks increase. For example, as $A$ have more and more blanks, does the the difficulty monotonically increase (or monotonically decrease)? Or is the problem most difficult when $A$ has roughly half blanks, then gets easier if $A$ is mostly blanks or mostly not blanks?

I don't see any general strategy. For the example, row two can't be a multiple of any other row. Any one of the other rows could be a multiple of any other one of the other rows, but it can't be the case that two of them are multiples of the third one. Could it happen that, say, rows one, two, and three are dependent, and four is a multiple of three? I think that the kind of reasoning you'll always have to go through.

Yes, it would be appropriate to say that some set of rows are independent of each other, and the remaining rows can be attained through elementary row operations. That would imply that the minimum rank of the matrix is not $1$, but some number $> 1$; however, we are not given what that rank is! This is what makes this problem so difficult (to me, at least)
